# npm violacion del segmento ( `core' generado)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, aplicación-web, npm

Me he encontrado con un problema instalando [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) y [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) en mi computadora (*Ubuntu 19.04*), pues al intentar hacer cualquier cosa con *npm* la terminal arroja el siguiente error, por ejemplo:

```
$ npm -V

Violacion del segmento (`core` generado)
```

Es la primera vez que veo este error, así que no tengo ni la menor idea de cómo solucionarlo (quizá influya que *Ubuntu 19.04* está muy reciente).
De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que se me pueda brindar :)

Comment: ese tipo de errores generalmente están relacionados al intento de acceder a bloques de memoria que no están asignados o que no existen, sucede mucho en C/C++, tienes otro dato adicional?

Comment: eso he notado buscando errores relacionados, la verdad es que no tengo ningun dato mas :( solo le que pues puedo especificar en el texto mas de eso no tengo ni la minima idea

Comment: has intentado resolverlo según lo que indican en este issue? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2763

Comment: acá hay una situación similar a la tuya que parece resuelta https://askubuntu.com/a/647177

Comment: ya lo intente con inclusive la ultima actualizacion, mas no funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Me acabo de encontrar con el mismo problema y tampoco me funcionó ninguna de las soluciones en https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2763. En mi caso es un proyecto de Angular y tengo Ubuntu 21.4. Tengo puesto `nvm` y me instalé las dependencias del proyecto con la versión  10.7.0 de `node` con `npm` 6.1.0. Pero las siguientes ejecuciones de `npm` disparaban **"Abortado ('core' generado)"**. Esto no es lo más correcto, pero cambié la versión de `node` con `nvm` a la 16.13.2 y `npm` deja de lanzarme este error.